# Error with magento 1.9 - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'domain name.log_visitor' doesn't exist

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

There has been an error processing your request

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'domain name.log_visitor' doesn't exist
Trace:
#0 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#4 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#5 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#6 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor', Array)
#7 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#8 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#12 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#14 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#15 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#16 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/cgit/public_html/mimfair.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Error log record number: 1250936715985

Problem Image:
http://mimfair.com/screenshot_15.jpg

Comment: Is this a fresh install of 1.9 or did you try to clear the log_visitor table by dropping it instead of truncating it?

Comment: I solved it by editing table method to create Schema::create('mytable', function (Blueprint $table) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that somehow your log_visitor table doesn't exist. Do you have access to the DB through some mysql client such as phpmyadmin? Execute this SQL statement to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE log_visitor (
  `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `session_id` char(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `first_visit_at` datetime default NULL,
  `last_visit_at` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_url_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`visitor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='System visitors log';
```

That should solve the problem

Comment: login to admin; clear magento cache, index and see if it works

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''log_visitor' ( `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, ' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, it had some extra quotes, should be fixed now.

Comment: Just copy the code again, I've edited the answer, correcting it.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'store_id' in 'field list'

Comment: This problem is solve. but second issue:  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'store_id' in 'field list'

Comment: shouldn't engine be innodb?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Corrected. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who ever has this issue:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_visitor_online` (   `visitor_id`
>   bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Visitor ID',
>   `visitor_type` varchar(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Visitor Type',
>   `remote_addr` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Remote Address',
>   `first_visit_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'First Visit
>   Time',   `last_visit_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Last
>   Visit Time',   `customer_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL COMMENT
>   'Customer ID',   `last_url` varchar(255) default NULL COMMENT 'Last
>   URL',   PRIMARY KEY  (`visitor_id`),   KEY
>   `IDX_LOG_VISITOR_ONLINE_VISITOR_TYPE` (`visitor_type`),   KEY
>   `IDX_LOG_VISITOR_ONLINE_FIRST_VISIT_AT_LAST_VISIT_AT`
>   (`first_visit_at`,`last_visit_at`),   KEY
>   `IDX_LOG_VISITOR_ONLINE_CUSTOMER_ID` (`customer_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB 
>   DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Log Visitor Online Table'

Answer (score 0):

The first answer seems to be missing the store_id column. Here's an update:

```
CREATE TABLE log_visitor (
  `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `session_id` char(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `store_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `first_visit_at` datetime default NULL,
  `last_visit_at` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_url_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`visitor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='System visitors log';
```